# Dynamic WPF Image Loading Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an issue that I think has not been covered in the multitude of other WPF image loading issues.  I am scanning in several images and passing them to a "Preview Page".  The preview page takes the image thumbnails and displays what a printout would look like via a generated bitmap.

The weird thing to me is, it will work fine if I run the program the first time.  Upon reaching the end of the process and hitting "start over", the preview will return blank.  I am creating the BitmapImage in a method that saves the bitmap as a random file name so I do not believe theres a lock on the file the second time around.  Also, if I go to look at the temporary file created through explorer, it is drawn correctly so I know the appropriate data is getting to it.

Finally, when I navigate away from this page, I am clearing necessary data.  I'm really perplexed and any help would be appreciated.

```
//Constructor
public Receipt_Form() {
    InitializeComponent();

    printData = new List<Object>();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // populates global variable fileName
    var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => outputToBitmap());         task.ContinueWith(t => setImage(fileName),
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

   // I started the image creation in a separate thread because I 
   // thought it may be blocking the UI thread, but it didn't matter
}

private void setImage(string imageURI) {
    BitmapImage image;

    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(imageURI)) {
        image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.StreamSource = stream;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.EndInit();
    }

    receiptPreview.Source = image;
    //this works the first iteration but not the second, though the temp file is created successfully
}
```

Comment: Where is the sense in saving a temporary file? Why not directly return the created bitmap from the `outputToBitmap` method?

Comment: I was doing that initially but I changed it to the current state for debugging purposes (viewing the created image).

Comment: And what exactly means "hitting start over"? Is that a special functionality in your program?

Comment: Essentially the user is navigating between 3 html based forms.  On the last one, upon completion the program navigates back to the first.

Comment: And then `MainWindow_Loaded` is called once again? It's not clear what happens during "start over".

Comment: There is a page prior to this one where data is scanned in (for the first time or repeatedly).  Then it navigates to the code snippet shown (whether it be the first time or nth time.)

Comment: have you ried to change the event to OnRendered? because i had some Issues with the Loaded event (gif animation was not working in may case).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the issue - the Modern UI container was getting cleared when transitioning off the page.